# Which is the better lens: Canon 28-80 USM I, 28-70 f/3.5-4.5 II or 28-105 f/3.5-4.5 II?

Tags: lens, canon, zoom

I own a Canon 6D and I need a general purpose zoom but I can't afford to buy an L lens, even an used one.

I've read [here](https://contrastly.com/old-inexpensive-sharp-canon/) about 28-80 USM I and 28-70 f/3.5-4.5 II. The author claims that those lenses are sharp. I couldn't find any MTF or chart with those lenses on a FF camera.

At about the same price I can buy a 28-105 f/2.5-4.5 USM but from charts it seem its resolution is horrible. Apart from bad sharpness, it has very poor contrast. I've seen chart shot with it on this [site](http://www.the-digital-picture.com) .

Can 28-80 or 28-70 be any better?

Is there any better old, cheap consumer zoom from Tamron, Tokina or Sigma which can be had for around 100 USD used?

Answer (score 2):

The lenses you've mentioned haven't been manufactured for around 10 years and the $100 offers you see on eBay these days are all for pre-owned samples which are likely to have degradation that's more important than what the lens could originally do optically. Having that in mind, I'd go for the 28-70 since a smaller zoom range and a larger aperture mean the lens can be expected to be slightly better in quality than the 28-80.

One final option is to get both lenses and then sell the one you like less. You might lose a dozen bucks on so on the transactions, but you'd be able to personally test them out on your own camera, tripod and preferred settings.

Answer (score -10):

Seriously, sell it all and buy Zeiss lenses. I guess they make them for Canon. I used Canon for years and they just fell to bits in no  time. As for sharpness, dont even bother looking at Canon. They are good enough off the shelf but soon get worn out very quickly. Plus Canon keep changing mounts. Go Nikon with Zeiss lenses if you wanna stand out from the crowd.

Comment: 'Canon keep changing their mounts'.. the EF mount has been used since 1987 and is still being used.

Comment: Also -1 this answer feels more like a 'I don't like Canon' then answering the question.

Comment: -1 for hear-say, non-informed bashing / promoting.